# Sqlplus Segmentation fault

Tags: oracle, segmentation-fault, sqlplus

I am getting a Segmentation fault when trying to login to Oracle through sqlplus.

```
gary@gary-desktop /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64 $ sqlplus web@DEV1
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Thu Jul 17 13:26:13 2014
Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 
Segmentation fault
```

I can connect successfully with Oracle JDBC This client(ojdbc6.jar). My url looks like this: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.153.72:1521:DEV1`

My OS is Linux Mint 14 Nadia

I installed installed the following oracle packages:

```
 - oracle-instantclient12.1-basic_12.1.0.1.0-2_amd64.deb
 - oracle-instantclient12.1-devel_12.1.0.1.0-2_amd64.deb
 - oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

`tnsnames.ora` looks like this:

```
DEV1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.153.72)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = DEV1)
    )
  )
```

If anyone has the answer I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was trying to connecting to an Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 server.

After uninstalling instant client 12.1.0.1.0 and installing instant client 11.2.0.3.0 everything worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

this is linking problem you must try this Another option would be re-install Oracle database software but relinking is a much faster.

```
   $ORACLE_HOME/bin  
              relink all
```

Comment: The is no relink in $ORACLE_HOME/bin. Only adrci, genezi and sqlplus

Comment: must refer to relinking executable on this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b15658/cnfg_prd.htm

Answer (score 0):

Using sudo works for me.

sudo ./sqlplus

That's because i read it couldn't access to the memory.